# Create wifi hotspot but block access certain domains

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

When I share my internet connection other devices think that they are connected to a WiFi (which is correct). Some programs such as dropbox, play music or updates start using a lot of bandwidth.
Is there any other way to block access to certain domains when creating a hotspot?

Comment: There's a setting on "the other end" (i.e. the clients using your WiFi), provided they run Android: in *Settings › Data usage* one can define a WiFi AP as "mobile hotspot". The system then will tell those apps to behave as if they were on mobile data.

Comment: @Izzy: This does not answer my question, but solves my problem! Thanks. I am still wondering if there is a "better" hotspot software on android available.

Comment: I was aware this isn't an answer (hence the comment), but was hoping it might prove helpful – which it turned out to be. Sure there are alternative hotspot solutions/apps, but none that solve your issue: all the client gets to see is a WiFi hotspot. I'm not aware of any "switch" an hotspot could use to tell the client "please be modest, I'm a bit limited".